# Generating AST from ANTLR Grammar: arrays inside structs

Tags: antlr, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to parser and generate an AST from an ANTLR grammar. I'm finding some problems when I try and parse arrays inside structs and array of structs.

This is a declaration example:

```
TYPE MY_ARRAY : 
     ARRAY [ 0..2 ] OF INT;
END_TYPE

TYPE est :
     STRUCT
          c1 : INT;
          c : MY_ARRAY;
     END_STRUCT;
END_TYPE

TYPE MSA : 
    ARRAY [ 0..2 ] OF est; 
END_TYPE

VAR 
      MA : MY_ARRAY;
      STR : est;
      STR2 : MSA;
END_VAR
```

I have no problems with declarations. I'm not able to write a grammar to parse expressions as next:

```
STR.c[1]
STR2[2].c[1]
```

Next code shows an extract of my ANTLR grammar:

```
operand
    : variable_simbolic
    | DIRECT_VAR<Localization>
    | CTE_INT<ConstantINT>
    | CTE_BOOL<ConstantBOOL>
    | CTE_REAL<ConstantREAL>
    ;

variable_simbolic
    : (ID -> ID<Identificador>) ( (('[' operand (',' operand)* ']') -> ^(ARRAY_ACCESS<ArrayAccess> ID<Identificador> operand+))
                    | (('.' operand )   -> ^(FIELD_ACCESS<FieldAccess> ID<Identificador> operand))
                    | (('#' operand )   -> ^(ENUM_ACCESS<EnumAccess> ID<Identificador> operand))
                    )?
    ;
```

This grammar allows me to parse expressions like `STR.c1` or `MA[1]`, but it doesn't parse expressions like `STR.c[1]`. If an array access is defined, it has to be the parent expression. I hope next diagram helps:

[image: AST output]

Is there any way to modify my grammar to accept that kind of expressions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
operand
 : variable_simbolic
 | CTE_INT
 ;

variable_simbolic
 : (ID -> ID) (variable_simbolic_tail -> ^(ID variable_simbolic_tail))?
 ;

variable_simbolic_tail
 : array variable_simbolic_tail?  -> ^(ARRAY_ACCESS array variable_simbolic_tail?)
 | '.' ID variable_simbolic_tail? -> ^(FIELD_ACCESS ID variable_simbolic_tail?)
 | '#' ID variable_simbolic_tail? -> ^(ENUM_ACCESS ID variable_simbolic_tail?)
 ;

array
 : '[' operand (',' operand)* ']' -> ^(ARRAY_OPS operand+)
 ;
```

?

### EDIT

I propose a slightly different way. Instead of trying to construct a complex AST with many different levels, simply create a single `LOOKUP` AST and let the *tails* be added as child nodes to this ast.

An small example grammar:

```
grammar T;  

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  LOOKUP;
  ARRAY_ACCESS;
  FIELD_ACCESS;
  ENUM_ACCESS;
}

parse
 : operand EOF
 ;

operand
 : variable_simbolic
 | CTE_INT
 ;

variable_simbolic
 : ID variable_simbolic_tail* -> ^(LOOKUP ID variable_simbolic_tail*)
 ;

variable_simbolic_tail
 : '[' operand (',' operand)* ']' -> ^(ARRAY_ACCESS operand+)
 | '.' ID                         -> ^(FIELD_ACCESS ID)
 | '#' ID                         -> ^(ENUM_ACCESS ID)
 ;

CTE_INT : '0'..'9'+;
ID      : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'  |'0'..'9')*;
SPACE   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

If you parse the input: `STR2[2].c[1]`, you will get the following AST:

[image]

which is easily evaluated by walking the children from left to right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That grammar parses everything right, but it doesn't generate the AST node hierarchy I need. In your grammar, the root node always is an ID and I need ARRAY_ACCESS as root node, followed by FIELD_ACCESS and, finally, ID. Is there any way to do it? Thank you again.

Comment: I've been changing my language interpreter to use that grammar. Now, I can say it works perfectly. LR grammars are driving me crazy (I'm used to LL grammars). Thank you so much for your help ;)